# WideCharToMultiByte returning junk characters for Japanese characters at codepage utf-8 in vc++ application

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8

I have some input Japanese string and one char buffer like below

```
TCHAR szvalue[256] = _T("はい");

char  aszvalue[256];
```

when I execute below call , I am getting junk value like `縺ｯ縺`

```
WideCharToMultiByte(UTF-8, 0, szvalue, -1, szMBBuffer, 7, NULL, NULL);
```

and also one more thing if i set codepage as 932 it is working fine,  but not with UTF-8.

Comment: How do you observe the result? What is the connection, if any, between `aszvalue` and `szMBBuffer`? What is the value of the variable `UTF`, and why are you subtracting 8 from it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Its coz the LPWSTR or (TCHAR) is not NULL-Terminated. The third argument in the function call (**-1**) indicates the function that your variable **szvalue** is null-terminated. Instead pass the length of your string as,

```
WideCharToMultiByte(UTF-8, 0, szvalue, wcslen(szvalue), szMBBuffer, 7, NULL, NULL);
```